# Update Call Logs using a ContentResolver and a LIKE operator

Tags: android

I would like to update the Call Logs using a ContentResolver based on a phone number. The code below works correctly. As you can see I am updating call logs where the Phone number matches exactly to the input number. However it is possible that phone numbers are stored in different formats. For example I might have dialled 04428763410, and while receiving a call, the number could have been registered as +914428763410. Therefore my question is, how do I update the call logs correctly? Should I use a 'LIKE' operator? If so, how should I frame my update statement? Please assist. Thanks.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, newContactName);

    int nRows = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,  values, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?", new String[] {mTempPhoneNumber});
```